# Linq - Getting calendar events that have Start and Length properties

Tags: linq, entity-framework, calendar

My application has a built-in calendaring system and the database schema for them looks like this:

```
CalendarItem( CalendarItemId bigint, Start datetime, Length int, Blargh nvarchar(MAX) )
```

`Start` is the UTC datetime value when the event starts, and `Length` is the length of the event in seconds. An all-day event starts at 0000h and has a length of 86400.

I'm using Linq with Entity Framework, and I want to find events that fall within a date range. It's easy to find events that start between two datetimes, but I don't know how to find events that also **end** between two datetimes.

Here's my current code:

```
public IEnumerable<CalendarItem> GetCalendarItems(DateTime from, DateTime to) {

    var events = from c in db.CalendarItems
                 where c.Start >= from && c.Start <= to
                 orderby c.Start
                 select c;

    return events;
}
```

If I were using T-SQL, I would need to use `DATEADD` to add `Length` seconds to `Start` to give an `End` datetime, which would then work, but I don't think I can do this in Linq. What can I do?

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.dateadd.aspx

Answer (score 2):

EDITED with ToList() function included:

If I'm reading this correctly, you would want:

```
var events = (from c in db.CalendarItems
             where c.Start >= from && c.Start <= to
             orderby c.Start
             select c).ToList();
events = events.Where(e => e.Start.AddSeconds(Length) <= to);

return events;
```

This will then give you the events that started and ended during the specified date range.

For more information about DateTime.AddSeconds(), just visit [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addseconds.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You will need to call `ToList()` first before you can use the `DateTime.AddSeconds` function. Otherwise the compiler will complain that it cannot find the `AddSeconds` function since your LINQ queries will be translated to SQL and SQL does not contain this `DateTime.AddSeconds` function.

```
var events = (from c in db.CalendarItems
             where c.Start >= from && c.Start <= to
             orderby c.Start
             select c).ToList();
events = events.Where(e => e.Start.AddSeconds(Length) <= to);
return events;
```

**EDIT: Corrected my logic, the answer is now identical to IronMan84's.**

Comment: Your events.Where clause will always return everything. e.Start is always less than e.Start.AddSeconds(Length). Please see my answer for a better solution.

Comment: @IronMan84 thanks you are right. Thanks for consolidating my answer into one.

Answer (score 0):

I evaluated the `.ToList` approaches, but they're inefficient because after modifying it to return events that occur (regardless of whether or not they started or ended within) a time period it fetches many irrelevant results from the database.

I also looked at the SqlFunctions methods, but they aren't present in EF1.0.

I ended up using a Sproc with a strongly-typed import on my Entity Context. It's not perfect, but it's better than the alternatives.

When the project is upgraded to .NET4 eventually, I'll switch to SqlFunctions. Thanks for all of the advice anyway!